# adding new labels and textboxs on button click

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-applications

This code should allows me to add new textboxs and labels every I click the button

```
 int numOfFeilds = 0;
    protected void More_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numOfFeilds+=1;

        TextBox_ID.Text = Convert.ToString(numOfFeilds);

        Label[] labelsA = new Label[numOfFeilds];
        TextBox[] textBoxesA = new TextBox[numOfFeilds];
        Label[] labelsB = new Label[numOfFeilds];
        TextBox[] textBoxesB = new TextBox[numOfFeilds];



        for (int i=0; i < numOfFeilds; i++)
        {
            labelsA[i] = new Label();
            labelsA[i].ID = "l_A_" + Convert.ToString(i);
            labelsA[i].Text = "Book Number";


            textBoxesA[i] = new TextBox();
            textBoxesA[i].ID = "tb_A_" + Convert.ToString(i);

            labelsB[i] = new Label();
            labelsB[i].ID = "l_B_" + Convert.ToString(i);
            labelsB[i].Text = "Amount";

            textBoxesB[i] = new TextBox();
            textBoxesB[i].ID = "tb_B_" + Convert.ToString(i);

        }

        for (int i =0; i< numOfFeilds; i++)
        {
            divFeilds.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
            divFeilds.Controls.Add(labelsA[i]);
            divFeilds.Controls.Add(textBoxesA[i]);
            textBoxesA[i].Text = Convert.ToString(numOfFeilds);
            divFeilds.Controls.Add(labelsB[i]);
            divFeilds.Controls.Add(textBoxesB[i]);
            divFeilds.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

        }

    }
```

But so far, It only works for the first click.

The value of numOfFeilds remains at 1 no matter how many time I click the button after the first click.

I don't understand why is that happening since numOfFeilds is out side of this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Time you click the button the value of numOfFeilds reset and starts from zero again.
Try storing the value of click in viewstate and then check from viewstate on each click.